# How to install additional drivers for Nvidia 1650 Ti mobile?

Tags: drivers, gpu-driver, additional-drivers

I have been trying to install additional drivers to my OS. My GPU is a Nvidia GeForce 1650 Ti mobile. I am getting a black screen and some unexpected crashes. My PC is also running hotter than usual. Is this because I could not install drivers for my devices? Can anyone help me install drivers? For now I know I have to install the GPU driver but if there are more drivers I should install please let me know.

Comment: Just open Additional drivers (or Software & Updates > Additional drivers tab), select, apply and reboot. You may need to disable Secure Boot in UEFI - the easy way unless you're dual-booting with Windows 11 - or manually sign the drivers with MOKutil.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I have already done this but did not solve.

Comment: Not an answer, just a comment. There are dozens of answers for this same question already. Which version have you installed? And have you did the other stuff? If so, how exactly? And a small detail that may or may not be relevant: There's no distinction for "mobile" in the 16 series and there's no "1650ti", only "1650" or "1660ti" so please check which one is yours exactly. The complete list of the 16 series is: 1630, 1650, 1660, 1660ti, 1650 SUPER and 1660 SUPER.

Comment: No you do not need to install *additional* drivers. You just need the appropriate driver for your hardware. This driver should have been automatically installed when you installed Ubuntu, as long as you checked the options to install updates during installation and accepted 3rd party proprietary drivers. Did you do that? Actually, attempting to manually install drivers after-the-fact can muddy the landscape and make it very hard to fix if you are not familiar with fixing problems in Linux systems. It sounds like your attempts are  what broke your system.  Could this be the problem?

Comment: @Nmath "Additional Drivers" is the GUI tool for proprietary drivers, Nvidia and others. Suggesting its use does not in any any means the user needs "additional" drivers. If the Nvidia drivers were already installed they would show up as installed in "Additional Drivers". The problem here is likely deeper or even different than what's being disclosed. Far starters we can't be sure about the actual hardware (cf. my comment above). And, of course, all my comments assumed the drivers aren't yet installed taking the OP's report in good faith.

Comment: @ChanganAuto notebook version of 1650 ti I checked what driver nvidia it suggest version 525 And I installed it from software&updates/additional drivers.

Comment: Again, there's no "1650ti". I've check at Nvidia too, hence why I posted the previous long comment.

Comment: @Nmath I have done them. For a time later my computer started crashes. I checked my about tab and I saw that my graphic card does not recognize. After These problems I tried to install appropriate graphic card drivers.

Comment: @ChanganAuto GeForce GTX 16 Series (Notebooks):
GeForce GTX 1660 Ti, GeForce GTX 1650 Ti, GeForce GTX 1650 I get this from nvidias site

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/vkZOG6d

Comment: @ChanganAuto https://imgur.com/a/3eCM845

Answer (score 0):

List all Nvidia related packages

```
dpkg -l | grep nvidia
```

Purge all the Nvidia related package you see in the list

```
sudo apt purge *nvidia*
```

When you have done this successfully

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

Reboot and now your system should work fine

You dont need "Additional Drivers".

Comment: After I purge current drivers. sudo autoinstall code did not work. I get this error message. (UnboundLocalError: local variable 'version' referenced before assignment
)

Comment: @exiort its broken right now sorry about that, please try sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525